# How to integrate $\int \frac{x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}}{1+x^k}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How would I do the following integral? 
$$\int \frac{x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}}{1+x^k}dx$$
Where $x > 0$ and $k$ is a constant greater than $0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Try substituting $x^{\frac{k}{2}}=\tan\theta$ and watch the integral fall apart.

Answer (score 2):

Setting
$$
z=x^{\frac{k}{2}},
$$
we have
$$
\int\frac{x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}}{1+x^k}\,dx=\frac2k\int\frac{1}{1+z^2}\,dz=\frac2k\arctan z+c=\frac2k\arctan(x^{\frac{k}{2}})+c,
$$
with $c$ an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
I = \int \frac{x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}}{1+x^k}dx
\end{align}
Let $t = x^{k/2}$ for which $x = t^{2/k}$ and $dx = (2/k) t^{(2/k) - 1} \, dt$ for which the integral becomes
\begin{align}
I = \frac{2}{k} \int \frac{dt}{1 + t^{2}}.
\end{align} 
This is the integral for $\tan^{-1}(t)$ leading to
\begin{align}
I = \frac{2}{k} \, \tan^{-1}(t) + c_{0}
\end{align}
and upon backward substitution
\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^{\frac{k}{2}-1}}{1+x^k}dx = \frac{2}{k} \, \tan^{-1}\left(x^{\frac{k}{2}}\right) + c_{0}
\end{align}